# PHP - use class functions inside string "" prefix not working

Tags: php, web

trying to use my class's functions inside a string in echo isn't working, probably because the string "", is there a better way to do so ?

this is my code :

```
class example{
    private $name = "Cool";

    function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }
}


$example = new example();

//THIS WONT WORK 
echo "the name : $example->getName()";
//THIS WILL PRINT :
//the name : ()

//THIS WILL WORK
$name = $example->getName();
echo "the name : $name";
//THIS WILL PRINT :
//the name : Cool
```

how can this be achieved inside the string ?

thanks

Comment: Read here http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php, look for `Complex (curly) syntax`.

Comment: If you really have to, this might work: `echo "the name : {$example->getName()}";`, but Andy Gee's answer is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `{}` when you are calling class function inside double quotes.

```
echo "the name : {$example->getName()}";
```

Answer (score 2):

Break out of the text block: `echo "the name : ".$example->getName();`

Answer (score 2):

You can either concatenate:

```
echo 'the name: '.$example->getName();
```

As CodeAngry pointed out, you can pass it to the `echo` language construct directy, too (to bypass concatenation):

```
echo 'the name: ', $example->getName();
```

Or use curly braces:

```
echo "the name: {$example->getName()}";
```

If you don't, in this case, the parser can't determine what part of the string is to be treated as an expression: do you want:

```
'the name {$example}->getName()';//where ->getName(); is a regular string constant
```

or

```
'the name {$example->getName}()';//where ->getName is a property and (); is a regular string constant
```

*or* does it imply a call to a method? PHP can't be sure, so you'll have to lend a helping hand by concatenating (not including the call in your quotes), which I personally prefer, *or* by delimiting the expression explicitly using curly braces.

Comment: **Concatenating on echo is weak**. You need to use the `,`. like `echo 'the name: ', $example->getName();` to prevent one pointless concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work as it works with variables. `$example->getName()` is a method (not a variable as it could be supposed).

Use like others suggest: put out of quotes.